# How to parse a Json to another activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

I have 3 activities that require a Json to show data, the second activity get the values from the main activity based on its ID, I need to pass that Json to each one of them so it can receive the data, How can I pass it through intent to another activity? I'm very new to android development, I've read some questions related to this case, but I didn't understand it very well.

```
public void updateList() {


        feedListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
        feedListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        feedListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, feedList));


        feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {


                TextView clienteId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clienteId);
                System.out.println("Clicou  " + clienteId.getText());

                int idCliente = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(clienteId.getText()));

                for(int x=0; x<feedList.size(); x++) {


                    if(feedList.get(x).getId_rm() == idCliente) {

                        ArrayList<ClientesContatosModel> contatosDoCliente = new ArrayList<ClientesContatosModel>();

                        System.out.println(feedList.get(x).getNome() + " tem " + feedList.get(x).getContatos().size() + " contatos");

                        if(feedList.get(x).getContatos().size() > 0) {

                            System.out.println("Valor de x " + x);

                            for(int y=0; y<feedList.get(x).getContatos().size(); y++) {

                                ClientesContatosModel mClientesContatosModel = new ClientesContatosModel();

                                mClientesContatosModel.setNomeContato(feedList.get(x).getContatos().get(y).getNomeContato() );
                                mClientesContatosModel.setCargo(feedList.get(x).getContatos().get(y).getCargo());

                                contatosDoCliente.add(mClientesContatosModel);

                            }

                        }


                        Intent intent = new Intent(FeedListActivity.this, FeedDetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("data", contatosDoCliente);


                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                }

            }

        });



    }
```

Parse Json:

```
public void parseJson(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {

        try {

            JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("dados");
            feedList = new ArrayList<ClientesModel>();
            // parsing json object
            for (int i = 0; i < dados.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject item = dados.getJSONObject(i);
                ClientesModel mClientesModel = new ClientesModel();


                mClientesModel.setId_rm(item.optInt("id"));
                mClientesModel.setNome(item.optString("nome"));
                mClientesModel.setTipo_pessoa(item.optString("tipo_pessoa"));
                mClientesModel.setInformacoes_adicionais(item.optString("informacoes_adicionais"));
                mClientesModel.setCpf(item.optString("cpf"));
                mClientesModel.setCnpj(item.optString("cnpj"));

                feedList.add(mClientesModel);


                JSONArray contatos = item.getJSONArray("contatos");

                if (contatos != null) {

                    contatoList = new ArrayList<ClientesContatosModel>();

                    for (int j = 0; j < contatos.length(); j++) {


                        JSONObject data = contatos.getJSONObject(j);

                        ClientesContatosModel mClientesContatoModel = new ClientesContatosModel();

                        mClientesContatoModel.setId_rm(data.optInt("id_rm_cliente"));
                        mClientesContatoModel.setNomeContato(data.optString("nome"));
                        mClientesContatoModel.setCargo(data.optString("cargo"));

                        contatoList.add(mClientesContatoModel);

                        JSONArray telefone = data.getJSONArray("telefones");

                        if (telefone != null) {

                            telefoneList = new ArrayList<ContatosTelefoneModel>();

                            for (int k = 0; k < telefone.length(); k++) {


                                JSONObject tel = telefone.getJSONObject(k);

                                ContatosTelefoneModel mContatosTelefoneModel = new ContatosTelefoneModel();

                                mContatosTelefoneModel.setId_rm(tel.optInt("id_rm_telefone"));
                                mContatosTelefoneModel.setNumero(tel.optString("numero"));
                                mContatosTelefoneModel.setTipo(tel.optString("tipo"));

                                telefoneList.add(mContatosTelefoneModel);

                            }

                        }


                        mClientesModel.setContatos(contatoList);
                        mClientesContatoModel.setTelefone(telefoneList);

                        System.out.println(mClientesContatoModel);
                    }


                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
intent.putExtra("json", (java.io.Serializable) new JSONArray().toString());
```

and in my second activity:

```
Bundle parametros = getIntent().getExtras();

        String jsonArray = parametros.getString("json");

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonArray);

            System.out.println("json array " + array.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can I get "telefones" from the main json and pass it in the second activity?

Comment: you can send the json as string inside intent to your activities

Comment: @IllegalArgument that is exactly what I want, but I don't know how to do that, can you give me an example how would I do that?

Comment: `How to parse a Json to another activity` or how to pass? if parse the in the same way as in the first ctivity ... if pass the in the same way as other object (they have to be simple object(int,string, etc), Parcelable or Serializable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing values through Intents, you can try creating a single object to store your JSON responses, then reference this object from your activity:

```
public class DataObject{

    private DataObject(){} // only one instance allowed
    public JSONArray telefone;

    public set_values(){
        // set your JSON stuff here
        telefone = data.getJSONArray("telefones");        
    }

}
```

Now you can reference this object from **any** activity...

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{
    private JSONArray telefone;

    private void get_values(){
        this.telefone = DataObject.telefone;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**STEP-1**:

Use this code to make HTTP request (for the `url` pass in your url)

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 500);

Client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
httpget = new HttpGet(url);
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
mContent = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

Then use this to get your data:

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mContent);
   String telefone = jsonObject.getJSONArray("telefones");
```

---

**OUTPUT**:: `String url` has the  data you are searching for !

---

**Note**::

- for the `url` you have to pass your url from which you are trying to
  get the JSON response
- Also place the above code inside an `Asynchronous task` otherwise it
  crashes because since you are making a network request

---

**STEP-2**: <***Eg:: From Activity1***>

Pass the `telefone`  into a new activity with the help of intents

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name",telefone);
startActivity(i);
```

---

**STEP-3**: <***Eg:: From Activity2***>

Receive the string passed in another activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

---

***Hope this helps! Revert back if you have any errors.***